# Spring Cloud Quick Start not working

Tags: maven, spring-cloud

I followed the steps of the Spring Cloud quick start (https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/). The dependencies is here:

```
<dependency>
<groupId></groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId></groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Without the groupId, Maven gives me an error.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

try it,you can add the group id to org.springframe.boot

Comment: thanks.is there any solutions without adding the group id?